# Why does MS Excel change my conditional formatting rules when run as a macro?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, conditional-formatting

I have some pretty standard conditional formatting rules set up to help monitor my organisations printer toner levels. When the rules are applied "manually" everything works fine and the output looks like this:

[image: Image1]

When the conditional formatting is applied as part of a macro, the previous steps of which extract the relevant columns from the wider report, the output looks like this:

[image: Image2]

Troubleshooting steps tried to no avail include, but are not limited to:

1. Saving the generated .csv file generated by clicking on the Report
   button as a .xlsm file before running the macro.
2. Saving the macro in
   the Personal Macro Workbook as opposed to the active workbook.
3. Changing the order of the conditional formatting rules.

The grey fill is applied to every cell in the last 3 columns and multiple cells in the first column when it shouldn't be and I have no idea why. I assume it's related to the rule for blank cells changing to that formula when the macro runs, but I don't know why that happens either.

Excel version: Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2202 Build 16.0.14931.20118) 32-bit

The macro was recorded rather than programmed, but here is the code:

```vb
Sub TonerLevels()
'
' TonerLevels Macro
'

'
    Columns("B:B").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=3
    Range("B:B,N:N").Select
    Range("N1").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=-3
    Range("A1").Select
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar:= _
        ":", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), _
        Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Columns("A:I").Select
    Columns("A:I").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("C4:C1048576,E4:E1048576,G4:G1048576,I4:I1048576").Select
    Range("I4").Activate
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=LEN(TRIM(I4))=0"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.249946592608417
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="=0", Formula2:="=0.04"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="=0.05", Formula2:="=0.09"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16754788
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 10284031
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="=0.1", Formula2:="=1"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16752384
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13561798
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
    Range("C4:C1048576,E4:E1048576,G4:G1048576,I4:I1048576").Select
    Range("I4").Activate
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="=0", Formula2:="=0.04"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Range("C4:C1048576,E4:E1048576,G4:G1048576,I4:I1048576").Select
    Range("I4").Activate
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="=0.05", Formula2:="=0.09"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16754788
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 10284031
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Range("C4:C1048576,E4:E1048576,G4:G1048576,I4:I1048576").Select
    Range("I4").Activate
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlBetween, _
        Formula1:="=0.1", Formula2:="=1"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16752384
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13561798
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Range("C4:C1048576,E4:E1048576,G4:G1048576,I4:I1048576").Select
    Range("I4").Activate
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=LEN(TRIM(I4))=0"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = -0.249946592608417
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-18
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you apply the CF rule with VBA, or do you only change the cell's value with VBA (but with the CF rules already specified manually to the range before running the macro)? You might have to paste your code as well.

Comment: Thank you. I have added the code to the question.

Answer (score 1):

**TO UNDERSTAND WHAT IS HAPPENING**

Critical points:

1. The rules are different:

   - Manually applied: `Cell contains a blank value`
   - Macro applied: `Formula: =LEN(TRIM(I4))=0`
2. The formatting changes the background color but not the text color. It only shows black in the image because that's the "Automatic" coloring.

Let's examine how this is applied in the cells that look different with the manual rules:

- Does the cell contain a blank value? No, OK, skip this rule.
- Is the cell value between 0.1 and 1? If so, turn the background and the text green.
- Is the cell between 0.05 and 0.09? If so, turn the background and the text yellow.
- Is the cell between 0 and 0.04? If so, turn the background and the text red.

There is no overlap among the last three conditions. (Side note: There are gaps for numbers like 0.095, though.) That means we don't have to worry about interfering rules. Anything with a value won't be blank which means there's no overlap with the first rule, either.

Now, let's look at the macro applied rules:

- Is the length of the value in I4 = 0? This cell reference is not locked so it'll vary among all the cells. The cell in the formula is used for the top-left cell in your "Applies To" range so: `C4` will use `I4`, `C5` will use `I5`, `D6` will use `J6`, etc. For the first several rows in column C, the corresponding cell in column I is blank so this formula returns TRUE. This is also true for everything in columns D:I since they will reference columns to the right of I which are all blank. However, the cells in the middle of your screenshot in column C *do* have corresponding values in column I so this formula returns FALSE. If false, the rule is skipped. If true, the background of the cell will be set to gray *but the text color is not changed.*
- Is the cell value between 0.1 and 1? If so, turn the background and the text green.
- Is the cell between 0.05 and 0.09? If so, turn the background and the text yellow.
- Is the cell between 0 and 0.04? If so, turn the background and the text red.

These rules *do* have overlap. Higher rules take priority. Since the first rule sets the background color, the lower rules can't change the background color. However, they *can* change the text color since the first rule doesn't set it.

---

**TO CORRECT THE ISSUE**

Option 1) Change the macro to use the same conditions as the manual method.

Option 2) Change the macro to reference cell `C4`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll edit the macro when I get the chance. But why is the macro referencing C4? Shouldn't each cell only look at itself when determining which conditional formatting to apply? I have noticed that cell C4 is the active cell after I have done all the highlighting, but I wouldn't have thought that would have been an issue.

Comment: @Skylore It's this line in the macro `"=LEN(TRIM(I4))=0"`. (It's in there twice for some reason.) That sets the formula the conditional formatting uses and it's hard-coded there to reference `I4`. If you change that to `C4` (and `C4` is the top-left cell of the "Applies to" range) then it should work.